# How do I access my web app from the Internet?

Tags: windows, web-applications, deployment, glassfish

I have deployed and run my app in glassfish v3 on my vps (running on windows web server). How do attach my app to my IP adress? (my domain is at use at the time so I need to access by IP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Managed to work it in glassfish app running!

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  Can you lay out the details of what you did?

Comment: I used glassfish via netbeans. instead of running it from the command line.